# How to set svg icon to background-image property in styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

I'm trying to set the SVG icon as a background image in my styled component and it's working fine in the local environment, but on the server, it doesn't work. I assume the problem is in the path. Here is the code of what I've tried so far

```
const IconComponent = styled('span')`
 .rdtNext > span:after {
   visibility: visible;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
   width: 13px;
   height: 10px;
   content: '';
   background-image: url('src/assets/svg/right_arrow.svg'); //this is with direct path and it doesn't work
 }
`;
```

And also tried importing it at the top of the file and using it as a variable like this

```
import rightArrow from 'src/assets/svg/right_arrow.svg';

const IconComponent = styled('span')`
  .rdtNext > span:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 13px;
    height: 10px;
    content: '';
    background-image: url(${rightArrow}); 
  }
`;
```

and also as a prop

```
import rightArrow from 'src/assets/svg/right_arrow.svg';

<IconComponent backgroundImage={rightArrow} />

const IconComponent = styled('span')<{backgroundImage}>`
  .rdtNext > span:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 13px;
    height: 10px;
    content: '';
    background-image: url(${(props) => props.backgroundImage}); 
  }
`;
```

and none of the above works. What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

---EDIT---
The 'right_arrow.svg' looks like this

```
<svg width="13" height="10" viewBox="0 0 13 10" fill="none" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M11.47 5.06641L0.603027 5.06641" stroke="#707070" 
   stroke-linecap="round"/>
  <path d="M11.8721 5.06641L7.44507 1.06641" stroke="#707070" 
   stroke-linecap="round"/>
  <path d="M11.8721 5.06641L7.44507 9.06641" stroke="#707070" 
   stroke-linecap="round"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Everything is fine with the right_arrow.svg because I can load it locally with the first block of the code. @RobertLongson

Comment: Well you're right, right_arrow.svg is OK so the problem must be the path to it.

Comment: Do you use CRA? a specific webpack config? Difference in dev and prod settings? What is the actual content of the style `background-image` property in browser dev tools inspection, both in dev and prod?